# Multipart request via JSON not getting the response?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am facing  the problem in java is that when i make a request through JSON which is multipart that time i am not able to get the response from the server.

here is the reuest block of javascript:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({ url: "/iview",
                  secureuri:false,
                 fileElementsId:fileIds,
                 dataType:entity.config.dataType?entity.config.dataType:"text",
                 data:{appmode:entity.config.appmode,   
                 json:requestObject,"__RequestType":"ajax"},
                 success: function (data, status){
                  for(var ent in fileIds){
                                    entityObject[ent].object = document.getElementById(fileIds[ent]);
                                    entityObject[ent].object.id = fileIds[ent];
                                }
                                requestResponse(data);
                            },
                            error: function (data, status, e){
                                Cyberoam.removeOverLay();
                                Cyberoam.messageBox({message:reportlabels.ConnectionLostMsg,autoClose:true});
                            },timeout:30*60*1000
                        }
                    );
```

below is the code of servlet from where response is sent:

```
PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/plain");                
out.println(new String(("status").toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
out.close();
```

so please help on this to get the response of multipart request of JSON??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about this but your URL seems weird.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand exactly what this does?

```
out.println(new String(("status").toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Let's rewrite it so that we can look at the different parts.

```
String s1 = "status";
String s2 = s1.toString();
byte[] bytes = s2.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s2 = new String(bytes);
out.println(s2);
```

This is what's happening:

- You have a string which contains "status", and you call `toString()` on it. That does nothing.
- Then you convert the string to a byte array. The byte array will contain the content of the string, encoded in UTF-8.
- Then you interpret the bytes back into a string. You don't specify the character encoding, so the default character encoding of your system is used, which may or may not be UTF-8.
- Then you print the result (which may or may not contain "status", depending on the default character encoding of your system) to `out`.

This most likely does not do what you want. You could just have written:

```
out.println("status");
```

if that is what you wanted.

Find out exactly what response should be sent from the Java code, and write code to send the response in the correct format.

Comment: this is just the example i am showing..because i am not getting anything from server. that was my server variable but for posting here i have replaced it.but forgot to replace the big code..sorry for that,